# Why do ImageView class setImage methods get ignored when there is a second setImage method beneath the first one?

Tags: image, javafx, imageview, fileinputstream, java-threads

I'm trying to display 2 images on user mouse click. The first image should be displayed, then a pause occurs, and then the second image displays.

Ultimately I want both images to display one right after the other for the duration of the program's execution.

I'm trying to use a while loop to first display image1, sleep, display image2, and then loop back to the beginning of the loop.

What ends up happening on mouse click is that the loop iterates 4 times with a 1 second delay on each iteration and after the loop is done looping, the second image is displayed only once and the first image display line of code is completely ignored the entire time.

The expected output was:

Loop Start
iteration 1: Display image1, sleep 1 second, Display image2
iteration 2: Display image1, sleep 1 second, Display image2
iteration 3: Display image1, sleep 1 second, Display image2
iteration 4: Display image1, sleep 1 second, Display image2
Loop End

What ends up happening is:

Loop Start
iteration 1: sleep 1 second
iteration 2: sleep 1 second
iteration 3: sleep 1 second
iteration 4: sleep 1 second
Loop End
Display image2

```
            int x = 0;
            while (x < 4) {
                iView.setImage(image1);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                iView.setImage(image2);
                x++;
            }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: don't sleep on FX Application thread, it processes all UI actions and updates — can't do it while dreaming. For pauses like that — use Timelines or other threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task/9966213

Comment: Thanks @SergeyGrinev that solved my problem perfectly.